# Fetch specific boost version with apt-get

Tags: ppa, plex, boost

To make my plex server run nicely I would like to fetch boost library version 59...

```
$ /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Plex\ Media\ Scanner --help
/usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Plex Media Scanner: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.59.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I would be glad to get it in binary from a trustworthy PPA but I don't see one. For example there is a [boost-latest PPA](https://launchpad.net/~boost-latest/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) but it only offers versions up to 55, as of this posting.

I don't mind building it from source, but I would like to do it in a way that my package management system is aware of my update. Fetching a zipped tarball etc. from Boost directly doesn't allow this.

Have I missed a way to do this with apt-get?